# Core Data with MagicalRecord does not save to iCloud

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud, magicalrecord

I am using MagicalRecord in my project. It has been working fine so far with a SQLite store.
But now I am trying to "upgrade" to iCloud to have sync between my iPhone and iPad versions.

But it is not working as I expected. The app still works the same - data is getting saved and read back, but it is not saved in iCloud as I would expect.

The only change I have made is in the MagicalRecord setup.

Before:

```
[MagicalRecordHelpers setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"hdhomerun.sqlite"];
```

After:

```
[MagicalRecordHelpers setupCoreDataStackWithiCloudContainer:@"AAAAAAAAAA.com.unpaq.hdhomerun" localStoreNamed:@"hdhomerun_local"];
```

The AAAAA's are not AAAAA's in the code, but my private ID from developer profile.

I can see in the output log that iCloud is detected and no errors occur. I also tried stepping through the code and it all looks fine.

What am I missing? Do I need to listen to some event?
I have not been able to find an example of how to use MagicalRecord with iCloud.

The version of MagicalRecord is this one:
https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: @JesseBunch No, not yet. I have to, before I release my 1.0. I will update this question, when I figure it out.

Comment: After looking through the forums, there seem to be a lot of issues with iCloud and Core Data. I'm downloading the latest beta now to see if my issues are fixed.

Comment: @JesseBunch Thanks for taking a look at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'll answer my own question.

MagicalRecord, at the point when I was using it, did not work with iCloud.

But it has recently been fixed by this commit:
https://github.com/emrosenf/MagicalRecord/commit/8415276615d9a9e12db9c0207bae373b7397dd56

And now it is working fine.

Comment: But can you explain in brief steps to sync my sqlite file

Comment: [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"MySqlite.sqlite"];


[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithiCloudContainer:@"111111111.net.mycompany.myapp" localStoreNamed:@"MySqlite.sqlite"];

Does this much does it all, what else to be done

Comment: Actually, it was working for some time and then stopped working. I have given up on Core Data + iCloud sync, as have many others. See: http://www.theverge.com/2013/3/26/4148628/why-doesnt-icloud-just-work.